# Identifying duplicates rows in an SQLite3 database and deleting them

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

I have a table `listed_users` that has two TEXT columns, `code` and `username`:

```
code | username
-----|---------
aa   | john_doe
ab   | jane_doe
ca   | john_doe
ca   | john_doe <-- duplicate
da   | ryan_doe
```

I'd like to write a command that will delete duplicates such as `ca   | john_doe`, where the same information appears in both columns in more than one row.

Comment: You should have checked the existence of the row before adding it again... Can the code column be the same, but with a different user?

Comment: Roughly to find the duplicate rows the query should be something like: `select code, username from listed_users group by code, username having count(1) > 1`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, a user can have more than one code listed.

Answer (score 8):

To delete one of a pair of duplicate rows, you must have some mechanism to identify it. In SQLite, this would be the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

The following query returns the `rowid` values of all the rows you want to keep, i.e., one row for each unique code/name combination:

```sql
SELECT min(rowid)
FROM listed_users
GROUP BY code, username;
```

You want to delete all rows not in that list:

```sql
DELETE FROM listed_users
WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT min(rowid)
                    FROM listed_users
                    GROUP BY code, username);
```